# Browserify requires not available in web console

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, console, browserify

Is there a way of making libraries - included using Browserify - available in the console?

e.g. I have a `functions.js` file containing:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('./_backbone');
```

Where `./_backbone` is a separate file (`_backbone.js`) with a backbone app in it containing code such as:

```
var testApp = {}; // create namespace for our app

testApp.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: '',
        completed: false
    }
});
```

Now, in the console I should be able to run this:

```
var todo = new testApp.Todo({title: 'Learn Backbone.js', completed: false});
todo.get('title');
```

And see the title displayed.

But I get a `testApp is not defined` error, leading me to believe the console isn't picking up the file (even though the page is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, mount testApp on window explicitly for testing purposes.

`window.app = testApp;`